# Golang communicate with AMQP through Websocket

Tags: go, websocket, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an application in Golang communicating with a RabbitMQ server with the protocol AMQP.

I would like to transform the AMQP into HTTP to avoid issues with firewall.

I thought about using Websocket to do this but I don't really know how to do this and even if it is possible to do it in Golang.

I successfully try to etablish a connection to my server Rabbit and to a Websocket but I don't know how can I link them

Can someone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's not enough information in this question to give a direct answer without making assumptions. Check out the guide on creating [Minimum, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) — perhaps the minimum working code you have for both the websocket and rabbitmq setup. Then we can adapt the answer to your exact problem. :)